# Converting to complex form(understanding example with solution)

Tags: complex-numbers

Determine the complex effective value of the sinus current:

$i(t)=\hat i_{1}cos(\omega t+\phi_{1})+\hat i_{2}cos(\omega t+\phi_{2})$

$\hat i_{1}=2,3A$
$ \phi_{1}=14{^\circ}$

$\hat i_{2}=1,8A$
$ \phi_{1}=-60{^\circ}$

**Solution:**

$i(t)=2.3Ae^{i14^{\circ}}+1.8Ae^{-i60^{\circ}}=3.29e^{-i17.7^{\circ}}=(2.214-i0.709)A$

**My questions:**

1. How they got $3.29$ and $17.7$?

2.How to get real and imaginary part in last step?

Comment: The 3.29 is wrong!!

Answer (score 0):

For the thing you're doing (where $\text{j}^2=-1$):

$$\text{I}\left(t\right)=\Re\left[\hat{i}_1e^{\phi_1\text{j}}\right]+\Re\left[\hat{i}_2e^{\phi_2\text{j}}\right]=\Re\left[\hat{i}_1e^{\phi_1\text{j}}+\hat{i}_2e^{\phi_2\text{j}}\right]$$

Now, use Euler's formula:

$$\hat{i}_1e^{\phi_1\text{j}}+\hat{i}_2e^{\phi_2\text{j}}=\hat{i}_1\cos\left(\phi_1\right)+\hat{i}_1\sin\left(\phi_1\right)i+\hat{i}_2\cos\left(\phi_2\right)+\hat{i}_2\sin\left(\phi_2\right)\text{j}=$$
$$\hat{i}_1\cos\left(\phi_1\right)+\hat{i}_2\cos\left(\phi_2\right)+\left(\hat{i}_1\sin\left(\phi_1\right)+\hat{i}_2\sin\left(\phi_2\right)\right)\text{j}$$

So:

1. $$\left|\hat{i}_1e^{\phi_1\text{j}}+\hat{i}_2e^{\phi_2\text{j}}\right|=\sqrt{\hat{i}_1^2+\hat{i}_2^2+2\hat{i}_1\hat{i}_2\cos\left(\phi_1-\phi_2\right)}$$
2. When $\Re\left[\hat{i}_1e^{\phi_1\text{j}}+\hat{i}_2e^{\phi_2\text{j}}\right]>0$ and $\Im\left[\hat{i}_1e^{\phi_1\text{j}}+\hat{i}_2e^{\phi_2\text{j}}\right]<0$:
   $$\arg\left(\hat{i}_1e^{\phi_1\text{j}}+\hat{i}_2e^{\phi_2\text{j}}\right)=-\arctan\left(-\frac{\Im\left[\hat{i}_1e^{\phi_1\text{j}}+\hat{i}_2e^{\phi_2\text{j}}\right]}{\Re\left[\hat{i}_1e^{\phi_1\text{j}}+\hat{i}_2e^{\phi_2\text{j}}\right]}\right)=$$
   $$-\arctan\left(-\frac{\hat{i}_1\sin\left(\phi_1\right)+\hat{i}_2\sin\left(\phi_2\right)}{\hat{i}_1\cos\left(\phi_1\right)+\hat{i}_2\cos\left(\phi_2\right)}\right)$$

   ---

For your problem we get:

- $$\left|2.3e^{14^\circ\text{j}}+1.8e^{-60^\circ\text{j}}\right|=\frac{\sqrt{853+828\cos\left(74^\circ\right)}}{10}\approx3.154650470394278$$
- $$\arg\left(2.3e^{14^\circ\text{j}}+1.8e^{-60^\circ\text{j}}\right)=-\arctan\left(-\frac{2.3\sin\left(14^\circ\right)+1.8\sin\left(-60^\circ\right)}{2.3\cos\left(14^\circ\right)+1.8\cos\left(-60^\circ\right)}\right)=$$
  $$-\arctan\left(\frac{1.8\times\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-2.3\sin\left(14^\circ\right)}{2.3\cos\left(14^\circ\right)+1.8\times\frac{1}{2}}\right)\approx17.7494464^\circ$$

And to answer your question (2):

$$\Im\left[2.3e^{14^\circ\text{j}}+1.8e^{-60^\circ\text{j}}\right]=-\frac{\sqrt{853+828\cos\left(74^\circ\right)}}{10}\times\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\approx-1.0024253669327538022$$

Where:

$$x=\frac{1.8\times\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-2.3\sin\left(14^\circ\right)}{2.3\cos\left(14^\circ\right)+1.8\times\frac{1}{2}}$$